# Making a data specific error turn into "Nothing"

Tags: replacement, warning-messages

This is a tad bit hard for me to describe (and the title doesn't help) but I will try my best to explain my problem.

I have a variable `data` that changes depending on whatever I put into it. The function I use applied several inputs `FUNCTION[#]&/@{1,2,3,4}` However, for certain data I create, there isn't a variable for `{3,4}`. I've written a ReplaceRepeated that transforms the output for `{3,4}` so that it equals `Nothing`.

My issue now is that I have to plot this data, and I format it all the same using the following:

```
MapAt[DateList@*ToString@*First, data[[3]], {All, 1}];
MapAt[DateList@*ToString@*First, data[[4]], {All, 1}];
```

Is there a ReplaceRepeated function that makes it so whenever there is an error I can somehow make it equal to Nothing? Something along the lines of `//.[ERROR] -> Nothing`

The question really boils down to, how do I take the error that is produced from

```
MapAt[DateList@*ToString@*First, data[[4]], {All, 1}];
```

and make it into `Nothing`?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:
Regarding what the result is, it looks something like this:

```
MapAt[DateList@*ToString@*
 First, {{{"20170609", 2.03}, {"20170613", 2.28}, {"20170627", 
 23.32}, {"20170703", 2.83}, {"20170727", 2.92}, {"20170731", 
 26.35}, {"20170803", 2.22}}, {{"20170613", 2.48}, {"20170703", 
 1.83}}}[[4]], {All, 1}]
```

However, the issue is when I change what `data` is, the values after `First,` change as well. I originally wanted to do something like this:

```
MapAt[DateList@*ToString@*First, data[[4]], {All, 
 1}]//.MapAt[DateList@*ToString@*
 First, {{{"20170609", 2.03}, {"20170613", 2.28}, {"20170627", 
 23.32}, {"20170703", 2.83}, {"20170727", 2.92}, {"20170731", 
 26.35}, {"20170803", 2.22}}, {{"20170613", 2.48}, {"20170703", 
 1.83}}}[[4]], {All, 1}] -> Nothing
```

However, once again,

```
{{{"20170609", 2.03}, {"20170613", 2.28}, {"20170627", 
     23.32}, {"20170703", 2.83}, {"20170727", 2.92}, {"20170731", 
     26.35}, {"20170803", 2.22}}, {{"20170613", 2.48}, {"20170703", 
     1.83}}}
```

would change after I change `data`.

Comment: What is the error? What's in the list after the application of your function for those cases that cause an error?

Comment: Hi MarcoB, I've made an edit.

Comment: Does `Quiet` help with the reporting of the error?

Comment: Sorry if I seemed unclear. It's not as much as getting rid of the error notifications, but rather making the result (which is from my POV an error since it doesn't apply the function to the data correctly) and making the whole thing `Nothing`.

Comment: What about something like `Replace[data, {s_String, v_} :> {DateList[s], v}, {-2}]`?

Comment: You can use `Check` e.g. `MapAt[...,Check[Part[data,4],Nothing],{All,1}]`...

Comment: Thank you for all the help guys! Found my answer. Used N.J Evan's method. Worked great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your problem originates when you try to extract a [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) that does not exist.  As [N.J.Evans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11777/n-j-evans) writes in a comment you could [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html) for `Part::partw` and return `Nothing` when it appears:

```
myPart1[expr_, parts__] := 
  Quiet[Check[expr[[parts]], Nothing, Part::partw], Part::partw]

myPart1[Range@5, 7]
```

> ```
> Nothing
> ```

*However* this method is vulnerable as if we turn [`Off`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Off.html) `Part::partw` it fails:

```
Off[Part::partw]

myPart1[Range@5, 7]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}[[7]]
> ```

If you only need to extract a single element at a time at the first level of the expression then you might explicitly check its Length; this works even with `Part::partw` off:

```
myPart2[expr_, p_Integer] := If[Abs[p] > Length[expr], Nothing, expr[[p]]]

myPart2[Range@5, 7]
```

> ```
> Nothing
> ```

Of course if you can avoid this entirely that is best, and I wonder where e.g. 4 in `data[[4]]` comes from that leads to this error.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment Mr. Wizard. You're right I did use N.J. Evans method in the end, worked pretty well since I haven't encountered any errors through testing. It was a relatively simple set of data so didn't need to extract  a single element at a time at the first level of the expression. Thanks again for the help!